# What is the cleanest way to sum elements in a list except the last one in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

The question is mostly out of curiosity, and because I've barely scratched the surface with functional idioms. I have a list of `Int`s where the last one is the checksum, so in order to verify it I need to sum together all the other ones. So far I came up with this:

```
val checksum = list.dropLast(1).sum()
```

Is it possible to do better?

Comment: Why not arrange your checksum so that when added to the rest, it gives 0, or a multiple of some big number?  (You could simply negate the sum, or [take the complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Sum_complement) of it. Parity checks and check digits are often done that way.)  Then you can just sum the whole list and check the result directly.

Comment: Yes, I could negate the sign of the last element so a full sum would result in 0. Very cool idea. In my case it works because I'm actually using an `Array` which is always mutable, however if I have an immutable `List` I would need to make a duplicate.

Comment: The elements of a list are meant to be homogeneous. While this holds for the element's type in your case, it does not for their semantics. Consequently you have to stop folding prematurely. I'd create a tuple/record to separate the checksum form the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something alike this might also work; in terms of selecting elements vs. dropping one:

```
val checksum = list.takeWhile{ list.indexOf(it) < list.lastIndex }.sum()
```

Or a whole lot more simple formulated:

```
val checksum = list.sum().minus(list.last())
```

What suits better merely depends if one later still needs to use that list for something else.

Comment: It seems that both `dropLast()` and `takeWhile { }` return a List, meaning they create another instance if I'm not mistaken. Isn't there some lazy alternative that uses `yield` like in Python and C#? Or in Kotlin is it actually the same?

Comment: In Kotlin, [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html) are the usual way of providing lazy iteration.

Comment: @MartinZeitler How does your first example handle the case where the last item is a duplicate of an earlier one?  (I think it also has very bad algorithmic complexity.)

Comment: @gidds This wasn't the question - nor the requirement; Using a [`Set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/) would eliminate duplicate items. Using a range would also be an option ... the neat thing with `.minus()` is that one can apply it to the list - as well as the resulting sum value (so one can change the order in the chain an still get the same result).

Comment: @gidds I see, but are sequences used under the hood by `dropLast()` and `takeWhile { }`?

Comment: @rdxdk The usual pattern is to create a sequence (from a list or whatever), and then apply the operations to that.  In this case, there's no Sequence.dropLast() method; but there are [Sequence.take()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take.html), [Sequence.takeWhile()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take-while.html), and [Sequence.sum()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sum.html).  I'd probably look at something like `list.asSequence().take(list.size - 1).sum()`.

Comment: The question is limited to `Int`, where the `-` solution (why write it as `.minus`?) should be correct. But it wouldn't work for floating point types, e.g. consider `listOf(0.0, Double::POSITIVE_INFINITY)`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler "This wasn't the question - nor the requirement" I think you misunderstand @gidds' point. Try your first solution on `val list = listOf(1,1)`; does it give the same result as `list.dropLast(1).sum()`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov My view is that this is `List` and not `String` and therefore it should return the index of the element and not of the value ...which each have their own reference in the JVM (opposite to a `String`). It's `indexOf` by value vs. `indexOf` by element's reference. If this isn't considered, it may be a shortcoming... it merely depends how an array of integers is actually being transpiled (eg. with a `byte[]` it wouldn't work either). I haven't tested or checked the output ...it can be that primitive arrays may be represented differently as I thought (not as an `ArrayList`).

Comment: If a `List<int>` won't work; an `ArrayList<Integer>` should (the question does not disclose what `list` is)... and based upon this uncertainty, it may or may not be applicable. I'll compare that later when I'll find some time ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler Well, it doesn't; it returns the first index of an element _equal_ to the argument. Though the documentation isn't explicit about that, but reference equality is something Kotlin and Java standard libraries very rarely care about, compared to value equality.

Comment: "What suits better merely depends if one later still needs to use that list for something else." I haven't even noticed this; no, it doesn't. Both solutions leave the list unmodified so you can use it again.